# When to Expose WCF over Internet

Tags: wcf, architecture

I have an internet-facing web-application (built in MVC), and a WCF service that is being used by the web app for data retrieval and some other operations.  Both applications are residing on 2 separate servers under same domain.

My question is, since the web app is facing internet, which means it has a public IP, do I have to do the same for my WCF?

Do I have to expose the WCF via internet?  or, should I set it up using local IP only since I can set-up end-point URL using local IP?

Am I correct to say that web app can communicate with WCF locally while exposing the presentation layer via internet?  That way, WCF is more secured.

Comment: Which machines do you want to access the WCF services? If only the server side of your web app, then no need for Internet access for WCF.

Answer (score 0):

Which machines do you want to access the WCF services? If only the server side of your web app, then no need for Internet access for WCF. If the client side of your web app needs access, then you need to expose WCF to the Internet.